# "O método getPreventDefault() não deve mais ser usado. No lugar, use defaultPrevented"

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet

Em algumas navegadores, como o `Google Chrome`, sempre quando em "mexo" em algum elemento da página, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead

Ou ainda:

> Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead

No meu Firefox 39, aparece:

> O método getPreventDefault() não deve mais ser usado. No lugar, use defaultPrevented..

Fico preocupado quanto ao desenvolvimento sempre que vejo ou escuto a palavra *Deprecated* ou *Depreciado*.

Afinal de contas, o que é que causa essa mensagem?

Isso refere-se ao `event.preventDefault()` que geralmente utilizamos com o `eventListener` e/ou com `jQuery`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como a própria linguagem JavaScript está a evoluir e novas normas são adaptados, algumas funcionalidades e métodos antigos vão sendo deixados para trás. Ou seja são "deprecados" e isso significa que no futuro deixarão de funcionar.

É sempre importante "manter o código", ou seja atualizá-lo para não ter erros em Browsers novos.

No caso de se estar a utilizar uma biblioteca é só mudar a versão para uma mais nova e testar o código a ver se tudo funciona da mesma maneira, sem erros.

Se for código próprio é procurar o método que substitui esse antigo e mudar.

No caso do `getPreventDefault()` isso era uma ideia da Mozilla que [foi removida](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=726933#c0). A ideia era saber se num dado evento o `.preventDefault()` tinha sido chamado. O método norma para fazer isso é [`event.defaultPrevented`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented).

No caso do `.returnValue` isso era uma ideia da Microsoft (Internet Explorer) e servia para cancelar/parar eventos. Também foi abandonado pela norma atual que é `event.preventDefault();`.